# Extracting comments/annotations from PDF sequentially - Python

Tags: python, pypdf, pdf-extraction

I am trying to extract comments from a PDF using Python. These are the two pieces of code that I have tested:

One using `PyPDF2`:

```
import PyPDF2

src = 'xxxx.pdf'
input1 = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(open(src, "rb"))
nPages = input1.getNumPages()

df_comments = pd.DataFrame()
for i in range(nPages) :
    annotation = []
    page = []
    page0 = input1.getPage(i)
    try :
        for annot in page0['/Annots'] :
            annotation.append(annot.getObject())
        page = [i+1] * len(annotation)
        page = pd.DataFrame(page)
        annotation = pd.DataFrame(annotation)
        df_temp = pd.concat([page, annotation], axis=1)
        df_comments = pd.concat([df_comments, df_temp], ignore_index=True)
    except : 
        # there are no annotations on this page
        pass
```

and the other using `fitz`:

```
import fitz
doc = fitz.open(src)
for i in range(doc.pageCount):
    page = doc[i]
    for annot in page.annots():
        print(annot.info)
```

The comments are getting extracted, however when I check the PDF I see that the comments are not being extracted sequentially. I have tried to check other parameters like creation date, modification date but that is not helping me.

Is their a way I can extract them serially as they are appearing in the PDF? Or Can I extract the text as well from the PDF against which the comment has been tagged?

Comment: A PDF is instructions to a printer for how to print a document. It's not structured for easy scraping. It doesn't say "here's a table of values, print them", "here's a header and footer, print them". It's just a mass of drawing instructions for lines, glyphs and bitmaps. The fact that PyPDF2 is able to achieve anything at all is almost a miracle. Whatever you manage to get out, it's up to you to make sense of it.

Comment: What does "sequentially" mean? By the time they were added to the document? By "reading flow", so the position in the document? By the last time the annotation was edited?

Answer (score 2):

I'm the current maintainer of PyPDF2.

The annotations are currently extracted in the order they appear in the annotations dictionary.

If you have a sensible way to sort them, feel free to open a feature request in the PyPDF2 issue tracker on github.